# sorting serialized data in GROUP_CONCAT() using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with these columns:

```
contest_id, exhibition_id, username, files
```

The column `files` contain pictures which I serialized while placing in the database because they are multiple files.
The column `files` looks like this

```
"a:3:{i:0;s:9:"10210.PNG";i:1;s:9:"99073.PNG";i:2;s:9:"89321.PNG";}"
```

I performed this SQL statement using PHP

```
$a = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT username,  GROUP_CONCAT(files) files from my_exhibition_contests WHERE exhibition_id='$id'");
```

and went ahead to write this in PHP

```
$s=$a->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
foreach ($s as &$row) {
    $row['files'] = unserialize($row['files']); 
}
echo json_encode($s);
```

Then I collected it at the front end using angularjs.
I used the `GROUP_CONCAT(files)` so as group it by username and put all the files with that username in a single row.
The problem is that using `foreach ($s as &$row)` defeated the purpose of `GROUP_CONCAT(files)`, it only brought one of the result as if I used `GROUP BY`, but on removing the `foreach ($s as &$row)`, it works the way I want it(i.e it packed all rows in files with that particular username in a single column with the alias name `files`) but the values in each index of files are serialized, in string format.
How can I unserialize each index of in the files array.
Let me give this example, let assume the first row in the table is like this

```
contest_id: 1 exhibition_id: 5 username: John files: "a:3:{i:0;s:9:"10210.PNG";i:1;s:9:"99073.PNG";i:2;s:9:"89321.PNG";}"
```

and the second row is like this

```
contest_id: 2 exhibition_id: 5 username John: files: "a:3:{i:0;s:9:"33937.PNG";i:1;s:9:"26831.PNG";i:2;s:8:"6316.PNG";}"
```

When I removed the `foreach` I got this

```
username: John files: "a:3:{i:0;s:9:"10210.PNG";i:1;s:9:"99073.PNG";i:2;s:9:"89321.PNG";},a:3:{i:0;s:9:"33937.PNG";i:1;s:9:"26831.PNG";i:2;s:8:"6316.PNG";}"
```

It puts everything in a single column files which is what I want but the issue is that it is serialized in string format.

When I put the `foreach` lines, I got this

```
username: John files : ["10210.PNG", "99073.PNG", "89321.PNG"]
```

This is in an array format, exactly what I want but it only brought the first row, how can I go about it so that it will be in array format, yet bring all the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to break apart the `GROUP_CONCAT`'ed file lists *before* you unserialize them, and then merge all the results. This should work:

```
$s=$a->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($s as &$row) { 
    $files = array();
    foreach (preg_split('/}(,|$)/', $row['files'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $filelist) {
        $files = array_merge($files, unserialize($filelist . '}')); 
    } 
    $row['files'] = $files;
}
echo json_encode($s);
```

[Demo of splitting code on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Bfs5X)

**Note**

We have to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the data because there are also commas in the serialized data. If you change your query to use a different separator that won't be present in one of the filenames e.g.

```
$a = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT username,  GROUP_CONCAT(files SEPARATOR '#') files from my_exhibition_contests WHERE exhibition_id='$id'");
```

then you could replace the `preg_split` with

```
explode('#', $row['files'])
```

This would also remove the need to add back the `}` split character to `$filelist` before unserializing.

Comment: wow, this is superb, exactly what I want. You also took your time to explain and dropped alternative, I really appreciate you.